# record metrics with timer in linux

Tags: c, linux

I need to capture some metrics such as time to send a tcp message and number of messages sent per second in c on linux.
I am wondering if this can be done via timer, such that whenever timer expires, i simply print the metrics. The main problem is that a timer can occur while metrics are being incremented and in that case, my signal handler would print corrupt data. Is there a way to over come this issue?

So the pseudo code in my mind was to declare a global struct which would contain send time for each send and count.

```
struct db
{
 struct sendTimes sendTimesPerSecond[10000]; // some large number which i cannot send in a second
 int count;
}
```

where

```
struct sendTimes
{
  timeval start_time;
  timeval end_time;
}
```

then provide few functions that would work on struct db such as

```
void record_send_time(pointer_to_db, sendTimes); // simply store the times
void incrementMessagesSent(pointer_to_db); //basically count++
```

Then i can do something like:-

```
signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
alarm(1)
struct db database;

for(;;) {
struct sendTimes sTime;
sTime.start_time = now(); // current time
send()
sTime.end_time = now();
record_send_time(&database, sTime);
incrementMessagesSent(&database); 
}


void alarm_handler(int signo)
{
  printf database;
  alarm(1);
 }
```

UPDATE:
Wildplasser comment about pipe seems to be the safest way to handle the above issue.

Comment: I dont know what you intend to do with `printf database;`, but I must warn you that printf() is not to safe in signal handlers.

Comment: BTW: the simples way to avoid printf or other races in a signal handler is to use a pipe: let the signal handler write to the pipe, and let main sit on a select() or poll() loop. No locking/semafores needed. Remember: write() is atomic.

Comment: @wildplasser wouldnt flipping a boolean variable's value in the signal handler be good enough as described in the UPDATE: section?

Comment: No, You would still get a race (who is going to reset the variable?) , and/or the main() needs to poll, and the variable would need to be volatile/sig_atomic_t, etc. Too messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alarm_handler to set a flag instead of printing from the signal handler.

```
int print_database_flag = 0; // global flag

  // ...
  record_send_time(&database, sTime);
  if (print_database_flag) {
     printf database;
     print_database_flag = 0;
  }

void alarm_handler(int signo)
{
  print_database_flag = 1;
  alarm(1);
}
```

Comment: double locking, i.e. in main and signal handler would result in deadlock. You could use reenterant lock, but that would then not protect the global data structure to be corrupted.

Comment: There is no locking in that example, just checking a single flag. I don't see the potential deadlock. Worst that can happen is that multiple alarm() calls will result in a single print at high load, which is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getrusage(2)` which has two `struct timeval` capturing time used up by our program in user (your code) and kernel mode (sends and the such).

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

.

```
struct rusage start, end;
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start);
// do what you have to do
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end);

struct timeval utime, stime;
timersub(&end.ru_utime, &start.ru_utime, &utime);
timersub(&end.ru_stime, &start.ru_stime, &stime);
printf("Work took %lu microseconds of user time and %lu microseconds of system time\n",
     (utime.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000) + utime.tv_usec,
     (stime.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000) + stime.tv_usec
     );
```

Comment: Ty for showing the getrusage and timersub. I was doing these calculations manually.